# Lucene does not index some words?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lucene.net

I use leucene.net for my site and it Index some of the words fine and correct but it doesn't index some words like "الله"!

I have see the indexed file with Luke and it shows that "الله"is not indexed.

I have used ArabicAnalyzer for indexing.

you can see my site at www.qoranic.com , if you search "مریم" it will be ok but if you search "الله" it shows nothing.

any idea is appreciated in forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ArabicAnalyzer` does some transformation to that input; it will transform the input `الله` to `له`. This is due to the usage of the `ArabicStemFilter` (and `ArabicStemmer`) which is documented with ...

> Stemming is defined as:
>
> - Removal of attached definite article, conjunction, and prepositions.
> - Stemming of common suffixes.

This shouldn't be an issue since you should be parsing the user provided query through the same analyzer when searching, producing the same tokens.

Here's the sample code I used to see what terms an analyzer produced from a given input.

```
using System;
using Lucene.Net.Analysis.AR;
using Lucene.Net.Analysis.Tokenattributes;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication {
    public static class Program {
        public static void Main() {
            var luceneVersion = Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30;

            var input = "الله";
            var analyzer = new ArabicAnalyzer(luceneVersion);

            var inputReader = new StringReader(input);
            var stream = analyzer.TokenStream("fieldName", inputReader);

            var termAttribute = stream.GetAttribute<ITermAttribute>();
            while(stream.IncrementToken()) {
                Console.WriteLine("Term: {0}", termAttribute.Term);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

You can overcome this behavior (remove the stemming) by writing a custom `Analyzer` which uses the `ArabicNormalizationFilter`, just as `ArabicAnalyzer` does, but without the call to `ArabicStemFilter`.

```
public class CustomAnalyzer : Analyzer {
    public override TokenStream TokenStream(String fieldName, TextReader reader) {
        TokenStream result = new ArabicLetterTokenizer(reader);
        result = new LowerCaseFilter(result);
        result = new ArabicNormalizationFilter(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: you were right and how can I prevent ArabicAnalyzer to change "الله" and index this word exactly as it is and not change it to "له" ?